# Grafana dashboard isn't populating any data (using Node exporter)

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm trying create Grafana dashboard to monitor our infrastructure, installed and configured Grafana, Prometheus. (using 1860 prebuilt dashboard)

configured/created datasource is fine, yet every graph is showing NA(not available?).

Grafana 7.3.7 | Prometheus 2.1.0+ds | Node Exporter 0.15.2+ds

Is there anything that I'm missing here, any help/pointers please.

followed this article - https://oastic.com/posts/how-to-monitor-an-ubuntu-server-with-grafana-prometheus/.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

- go to the Prometheus web UI and click on Status - Targets

  - is the node exporter in the list (if not, check your prometheus config)
  - is prometheus is able to scrape the metrics from node exporter
  - if not, can you crape them with your browser (or curl)
- if prometheus can scrape the metrics can Grafana access them

  - try the "Explore" feature to find some metrics exported by the node exporter

Comment: Thanks for your comment, these helped me to debug!!

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue!!!, Grafana is expecting latest Node Exporter 0.16 metrics while ubuntu's package manager has 0.15 which is older version. metrics are little different in older version for example node_cpu is replaced with node_cpu_seconds etc.

Ubuntu's package manager doesn't guarantee latest version, hence its advisable to always wget the latest package from source for tools such as this.

Comment: There are also dashboards for older versions on node exporter available. Unfortunately they changed their metric names, so  the old versions are not compatible with the new version.